# .net core MVC checkbox pre checked by model.item

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I got model and inside model we got "IsActive" with bool type. I want is when "IsActive" comes our View by "true", checkbox also start with checked and if it comes with "false" checkbox unchecked. How can i do that? Thanks for helping me!

```
<input class="togglecheckbox" type="checkbox" id="switch"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `checked` attribute:

```html
<input class="togglecheckbox" type="checkbox" id="switch" checked="@Model.IsActive" />
```

Comment: Thanks! i couldn't think smart :/

Comment: No problem. You actually found the answer before I posted mine ;)